# How not to send pending transactional emails

Tags: magento-1.9, email, transactional-mail

Because the magento cron was not configured correctly, I have several and several transactional emails for order confirmation, delivery confirmation, new clients, among others pending to be sent and when I set up cron correctly all the same would be sent all at once. I'd like to know how I could get all of these transactional emails out of the box, or that the client does not receive the same and all new emails are sent correctly.

In the core_email_queue table, are all pending system emails to be sent, if I give a truncate to this table, is it likely to create a problem or end up influencing some dependency?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you clean that table it should work flawlessly, i don't see there should be any dependency issue in any way. however you can review this post also :

[How do I clear all tasks queued in the Magento Cron, specifically emails?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156094/how-do-i-clear-all-tasks-queued-in-the-magento-cron-specifically-emails)